# Wanting time range using between SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

Will this give me the time range from yesterday at 10pm (2200hrs) to today at 8am (0800hrs)?

```
WHERE MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART between (trunc(sysdate-1) + 22/24) and (trunc(sysdate) + 08/24)
```

Comment: `+ 22/24` and `+ 08/24`? You're trying to add the result of a division operation? 0.916666666 and 0.333333?

Comment: Yes, It will. Why don't you print it and check for yourself?

Comment: @MarcB, Oracle treates a 24-hour period as being 1.0 long, starting from midnight. So 12pm is +0.5, 6am is +0.25, and the following midnight is +1.0, etc. So you can do +22/24 for example to get 10pm. Or even +10/24/60 to add 10 minutes; or +10/24/60/60 to add 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's trivial to see what range that gives you with a simple query:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

select trunc(sysdate-1) + 22/24, trunc(sysdate) + 08/24 from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)+22 TRUNC(SYSDATE)+08/2
------------------- -------------------
2013-07-28 22:00:00 2013-07-29 08:00:00
```

Two observations though. (1) Although using fractions for the time offset is fine, it might be a little clearer to use [interval literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#i38598):

```
select trunc(sysdate-1) + interval '22' hour,
    trunc(sysdate) + interval '8' hour
from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)+IN TRUNC(SYSDATE)+INTE
------------------- -------------------
2013-07-28 22:00:00 2013-07-29 08:00:00
```

And (2) `between` is inclusive, so if you're splitting the day up into 'shifts' you risk getting data recorded at exacltly `08:00` counted twice, which probably isn't what you want. To avoid overlaps you can just change that to:

```
WHERE MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART >= trunc(sysdate-1) + interval '22' hour
AND MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART < trunc(sysdate) + interval '8' hour
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex Poole! How would you say 0830?

Comment: @JonathanMorningstar - `trunc(sysdate) + interval '8:30' hour to minute`. Once you move off whole hours, the interval syntax becomes much cleaner than adding fractions of days, in my opinion anyway.